# Linear Algebra Basis Trick

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $F$. More generally, we can consider a free module $M$ over a commutative ring $A$, with rank $n$.

Let $(m_1,...,m_n)$ be a basis for $M/A$ and $(m_1',m_2',...,m_n')$ be another basis.

Any linear map $L:M\to M$ over $A$, has a corresponding matrix with respect to $m_i$ and $m_i'$. With respect to $m_i$ the matrix is given by $(a_{ij})$ where $Lb_j = \sum_i a_{ij}b_i$ and similarly for $(a'_{ij})$. We also have another matrix $(u_{ij})$, called the change-of-basis, from $m_i$ to $m_i'$, given by $m_j = \sum_i u_{ij}m_j'$.

I ***always*** forget the relationship between $(a_{ij})$ and $(a'_{ij})$. Of course, I can derive it, but it is annoying when one has to do it again and again. What is the right way to conjugate? Is there some easy-to-remember technique, most preferably, using a commutative diagram, that we can use? I really hate it when my train of thought gets derailed trying to figure out which matrix goes where.

As an additional question. How about those computations including the bilinear form matrix and its change-of-basis and those including discriminants of number fields with respect to a basis? Is there a generally convenient way of looking at this?

Answer (score 1):

The relation that uses the coefficients of the matrix  $(a_{ij})$ is wrong. Don't forget matrix multiplication is done multiplying $row$ of the first matrix by *columns* of the second matrix. So the relation is:
$$Lb_i=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}b_j$$

The change of basis matrix is also wrong: its column-vectors are made up of the coordinates of the *new* basis: $(m'_1,\dots,m'_n)$ in the *old* basis: $(m_1,\dots,m_n)$.

But it allows to compute ‘old’  coordinates (wrt the old basis) of a vector from their ‘new’ cordinates. So if we denote $X$ the column vector of coordinates in the old basis, $X'$ the column vector of the same vector in the new basis, $Y$ the column vector of old coordinates of the image of $X$ by $L$, and similarly for $Y'$, we have the relations ($A$ is the matrix of the transformation $L$ in the old basis, $A'$ its matrix in the new basis):

$$Y=AX,\qquad X= PX',\qquad Y=PY',$$
hence $$PY'=A(PX')\iff Y'=(P^{-1}AP)X'$$
so that $\,\,A'=P^{-1}AP$.

Here is a reminder in the form of a commutative diagram: both horizontal arrows are $f$, and both vertical arrows are the identity map, in the relevant bases. Just remember the change of basis from $\mathcal B$ to $\mathcal B'$ matrix is but the matrix of the identity map from $(E,\mathcal B')$ to  $(E,\mathcal B)$ :
[image]

Comment: To the person who downvoted my answer: what's wrong with this answer? One may find it unhelpful, or unclear, but mathematically it is not false.

Comment: There is nothing mathematically wrong with it. It fails to answer my question entirely. I know how to derive it. I just do not want to keep on deriving it every time I use it. I need a nice picture for it, like a commutative diagram, or whatever other trick.

Comment: @Nicolas Bourbaki: I added a commutative diagram. Hope it is clear (and remindful) enough.

Comment: I didn't know that $A'=P^{-1}AP$ needs a picture to be memorized!

Comment: @user26857: that's what the O.P. asked for. Note it may be somewhat confusing as conjugation in groups is defined with $x\mapsto gxg^{-1}$, and the two notions are tightly linked.

Comment: That's how I understood it, but I felt like explaining why I finally thought asking for some reminder was  not completely absurd.

Answer (score -1):

There's some notation, which I think I learned from Lang's *Algebra*, that seems to make these things easier. If $f\colon V \to W$ is linear and we have bases $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf w$ then ${}_{\mathbf w}[f]_{\mathbf v}$ is the matrix with respect to these. We have the property that ${}_{\mathbf w}[g]_{\mathbf v} \cdot {}_{\mathbf v}[f]_{\mathbf u} = {}_{\mathbf w}[g \circ f]_{\mathbf u}$.

Now, if I have two bases $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf v'$ for $V$ then your  change of basis matrix from the first to the second R is just ${}_{\mathbf v'}[\operatorname{id}_V]_{\mathbf v}$. And now you can use  the composition rule.