# Given is a linear mapping and a basis. Determine the transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations

> Given is $f: \mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$ with
>   $f:(x,y,z) \rightarrow (x+2y+z, y+z, -x+3y+4z)$. Determine the
>   transformation matrix in terms of the basis $B= \left\{\begin{pmatrix}
> 1\\  0\\  0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0\\  1\\  1
> \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
> -1\\  0\\  1 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$

$f(\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix})= \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
-1
\end{pmatrix}= 0 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} + 0 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
1\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}- 1 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$

$f(\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
1\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix})= \begin{pmatrix}
3\\ 
2\\ 
7
\end{pmatrix}= 8 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} + 2 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
1\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}+5 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$

$f(\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix})= \begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
1\\ 
5
\end{pmatrix}= 4 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} + 1 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
1\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}+ 4 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$

I'm not sure how to read the transformation matrix now. Either I will read it correctly or I will accidentally read its transposition :s

$T=\begin{pmatrix}
 0  & 8  & 4\\ 
 0  & 2  & 1\\ 
-1  & 5  & 4 
\end{pmatrix}$

Did I do it all correctly? If it's alright, there are maybe faster ways doing this?

Comment: What would you like the representing matrix of your linear transformation to do? I'd say -- agree with $f$ on the basis vectors. Does this help you to choose between $T$ and its transpose?

Comment: @uniquesolution I'm not sure if I understood you correctly but it seems like it's fine like that?

Comment: You don't seem to have decided whether $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the set of row vectors or the set of column vectors. That may generate confusion.

Comment: Looks right, but the notation of the matrix should be $[T]_B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a more straightforward way of computing the matrix is by using the relation
\begin{equation} [T]_\mathcal{B} = P^{-1} T P, \end{equation}
where $[T]_\mathcal{B}$ is the matrix that you computed,
$$P = (b_1\quad b_2\quad  b_3) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}, $$
and $$T = \begin{pmatrix} f(e_1) & f(e_2) & f(e_3) \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix},$$
where $e_1, e_2, e_3$ are the standard basis vectors. With this approach, all you have to do is invert $P$, which is easy, and then multiply the matrices. (check to see that it yields the same result!)

Heres a nice diagram that illustrates why the relation is true, from
 [Linear Algebra Basis Trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1147236/linear-algebra-basis-trick).

[image]